# JavaFX: Bidirectional Binding in FXML

Tags: java, javafx, data-binding, fxml, two-way-binding

I'm working with JavaFX, and am investigating data binding.
I've found that I can define a one-way binding in my FXML, like this:

`<TextField fx:id="usernameTextField" text="${controller.userName}" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />`

This means, that the text of the usernameTextField is 'observing' the controller.userName property.

But this creates a one-way binding. If the controller.userName property changes, I see the updated text in the text field, that part works. But I can no longer insert text into the text field, because I've made the one-way binding.

All I can find about this are posts which are now more than four years old, but I can't figure out, if JavaFX has been updated to support more elaborate bindings.

Answer (score 3):

The way to do that is:

```xml
<TextField fx:id="usernameTextField" text="#{controller.userName}"/>
```

But this feature is not enabled yet (last checked on OpenJFX 13) and using it will cause `FXMLLoader` to throw an `UnsupportedOperationException("This feature is not currently enabled.")`.

Comment: I stumbled upon that somewhere in another post, and the commenter found it was a bug, and should have been removed.

Comment: @Troels They've set aside the syntax for declaring bidirectional bindings in FXML but the actual implementation was never realized. There's an existing [enhancement request](https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8090665) which unfortunately hasn't been updated in over a year.

Comment: It just seems strange to do this so half-hearted, and provide part of the functionality and then dropping it. I don't like to have my GUI components referenced in the Controller. Thanks for the input, thouhg.

Comment: @Troels I also have a bunch of code lines that should've been removed from my controllers to FXML. Waiting for that feature to be enabled in future releases.

Comment: @Troels Note JavaFX is open source, which means anyone with enough time and motivation could [contribute this feature](https://github.com/openjdk/jfx/blob/master/CONTRIBUTING.md). Not suggesting you be the contributor, I'm just putting the information out there.

Answer (score 1):

As was already said there's no simple way to make a bidirectional binding from FXML. However it can be done from FXML, but not using FXML per se, so to say. And here are my findings.

### An `<fx:script>` block

The first and the most obvious way is to use `<fx:script>` to make whatever bindings are needed via JavaScript. For example one can use the following snippet to make a bidirectional binding:

```xml
<?language javascript?>
<!-- ... -->
<TextField fx:id="aControl"/>
<fx:script>
javafx.beans.binding.Bindings.bindBidirectional(
    controller.someProperty(),
    aControl.textProperty()
);
</fx:script>
```

Here `someProperty()` is a controller method for a property named `some`.

### A custom helper class

The second option is to create a helper class and then use it in an `<fx:define>` block (using the conventions from above):

```xml
<?import u7n.examples.BidiBind?>
<!-- ... -->
<TextField fx:id="aControl"/>
<fx:define>
<BidiBind o1="$controller" p1="some" o2="$aControl" p2="text"/>
</fx:define>
```

And here is an example implementation of such a class:

```java
package u7n.examples;
import javafx.beans.binding.Bindings;
import javafx.beans.property.Property;
public class BidiBind {
    private Object o1;
    private String p1;
    public Object getO1() { return o1; }
    public void setO1(Object o1) { this.o1 = o1; bind(); }
    public String getP1() { return p1; }
    public void setP1(String p1) { this.p1 = p1; bind(); }

    private Object o2;
    private String p2;
    public Object getO2() { return o2; }
    public void setO2(Object o2) { this.o2 = o2; bind(); }
    public String getP2() { return p2; }
    public void setP2(String p2) { this.p2 = p2; bind(); }

    private <T> void bind() {
        if (o1 == null || p1 == null || o2 == null || p2 == null) return;
        try {
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Property<T> property1 = (Property<T>)o1.getClass().getMethod(p1 + "Property").invoke(o1);
            @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
            Property<T> property2 = (Property<T>)o2.getClass().getMethod(p2 + "Property").invoke(o2);
            Bindings.bindBidirectional(property1, property2);
        }
        catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        o1 = o2 = null;
        p1 = p2 = null;
    }
}
```

It uses reflection to access properties because I haven't found a way to make FXMLLoader pass a property instead of its value to a setter.

### To sum it up

Neither way is ideal, but a bidirectional binding can be done from FXML, although not in a convenient way. Of course, something like

```
<TextField fx:id="aControl" text="#{controller.some}"/>
```

would be even better, but alas. Also I have no idea how well both proposed methods will work with Scene Builder as I don't use it.

Answer (score -2):

This code works perfectly :

```
<TextField fx:id="usernameTextField" text="${controller.userName}"/>
```

To operate, the controller must contain a getter :

```
public String getUserName() { return "mystringvalue"; }
```

Comment: No, this code does not work at all, and gives the "This feature is not currently enabled." error.

Comment: Edited, replace  "#{controller.userName}" by  "${controller.userName}"

Comment: And then it will be a UNIDIRECTIONAL binding, not BIDIRECTIONAL.